# SwiftUI Delete a List Section

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui, sections

Is there a way to delete an entire list section with a function in SwiftUI? I have a list that you can add sections to as you please, but don't know how to delete them when you want to. I know that you can delete a list item itself using the deleteItems function, but I would like to use a button to delete the entire section. When I try to use the standard "deleteItems" function, it asks for "offsets: IndexSet". I am unsure what this IndexSet would be.

I can't find out what should go in the IndexSet field.

Here is my code

```
struct SampleView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.categoryString, ascending: false)],
        animation: .default)
    private var listedCategory: FetchedResults<Category>
    @State var categoryString: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Enter Text Here", text: $categoryString)
            Button {
                let newlistedCategory = Category(context: viewContext)
                newlistedCategory.categoryString = categoryString
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
                categoryString = ""
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
            List{
                ForEach(listedCategory) { listedCategory in
                    if listedCategory.typeString == "Item" {
                        Section(header: Text(listedCategory.categoryString!)) {
                            Button {
                                //deleteCategories(offsets: <#T##IndexSet#>)
                            } label: {
                                Text("Delete")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteCategories(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { listedCategory[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Hi @barty9333 can you please share you code?

Comment: @darshilsakhiya I have updated it with code here. I want to use the func deleteCategories to delete an entire section from the list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555343/delete-item-from-a-section-list-on-swiftui. Check this link

Comment: Why would you want to delete a category using and index set ? Just create de deleteCategory method that will remove the category from your data as a category is equivalent to a section.